# Speedup UI in loading shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In global.R file I am reading some 10-12 excel files, some user defined functions, modules and doing some data manipulation (not so heavy task) on top of that. I want to speed up loading shiny app. I was thinking if I save it in .RData and then do `load("mydata.RData", envir = .GlobalEnv)` instead of reading excel files and sourcing functions in global.R. Would it improve loading time of shiny app? I am fine even if UI appears but server still loads. I am more interested in showing UI to the user instantly and user can wait for some calculation. I am using docker for production, hence mainly interested in UI loading time as container takes some time to spin up which user has to wait and then loading the app also takes time.

Comment: Try reading in the files async, https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/casestudy.html. Make sure you implement this in the global.R

Answer (score 2):

That is a big topic and there are several points in which you can improve your Shiny-App, so that it runs faster.

1. The first idea would be, to put every tab into a [module](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). Meaning that the code you normally run within your `ui.R` will get a lot shorter. Thus the app gets faster, since the plots, files, etc. what is needed within this module, just gets loaded once the user clicks on that tab.
2. Make your app more efficient by using `data.table`. This package is specifically designed for faster usage. You can even [combine](https://atrebas.github.io/post/2019-03-03-datatable-dplyr/) it with `dplyr`. In your case try loading your files with the `data.table::fread()` command.
3. When it comes to plotting you can even use JavaScript's D3. There is a [package](https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/) called `r2d3`, which enables you to use JS's D3 to plot within your Shiny-App.
4. Convert the excel-files into a more machine readable format, like .rds. This also increases the loading speed.

I would suggest, you once use the `profvis` [package](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/) and run your Shiny-App with it. It will allow, after you've loaded your app and closed it again, to see what exactly took so much time. Maybe it was not the loading after all, but a different problem instead? Then you could go from there.

Comment: Regarding 1.: this should be the default behaviour of shiny (at least for all outputs), and not unique for modules (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/outputOptions.html)